# Is there a paradox in between Plato and Aristotle's theories regarding moral decision-making?

Tags: aristotle, plato

I was responding to a classmate's forum discussion post in a class of mine, and I want to know if I created a paradox or not regarding Plato and Aristotle's theories of moral decision-making. This is essentially what I replied.
*Disclaimer: I removed the first sentence as it has nothing to do with the paradox:*

> My judgement senses optimism in the existence of a set of steps or formulas regarding decision-making, however there is also a strong argument on whether or not one exists. This strong argument is a theorem in mathematics known as Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem. This theorem states that "for any such consistent formal system, there will always be statements about natural numbers that are true, but that are unprovable within the system". The proof to this theorem is simple but it is hard to understand the validity of this proof. You can read more about the proof here: https://www.quantamagazine.org/how-godels-incompleteness-theorems-work-20200714/ (Links to an external site.) , but I can briefly explain it. Let's start with 12 math symbols and map them to numbers 1 through 12. We refer to these numbers that are mapped to them "Gödel numbers". Then let x = Gödel number 13, y = 17, and z = 19. You can create arithmetic formulas out of these as well. If you were to give a Gödel number of a formula, you would follow something like this: so let's take 0 = 0, since 0 is 6 and = is 5, 26 * 35 * 26 = 243,000,000. So the Gödel number of 0 = 0 is 243,000,000. Essentially, you get the product of exponents where the bases are ordered by the nth prime number, and the exponents are the Gödel number of the symbol in position n of the formula. Now let's make another Gödel number known as g, but the definition of g is that it cannot be proved. This is how Gödel's incompleteness theorem was proved.
>
> I believe that I have created a paradox in the paragraph above regarding both Plato and Aristotle's method of thinking. To recap, Plato believed that decision-making could best be determined by a mathematical formula. However, Aristotle believed that decision-making could best be determined by good judgement. I stated that "my judgement senses optimism in the existence of a set of steps or formulas regarding decision-making", but I followed that with a mathematical proof that debunked my judgement. Essentially, I believe in Plato's theory but debunked it with Plato's theory making Plato's theory false, but I used Aristotle's theory to believe in Plato's theory, but Plato's theory cannot be used to debunk Aristotle's theory because Gödel's incompleteness theorem only applies on consistent systems and Aristotle's theory is not a consistent system, but again I used Aristotle's theory to believe in Plato's theory.

Comment: Godel's theorem is more complicated than just mapping numbers to formulas, for example [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic) is a simpler axiomatic system that still has numbers and the addition operation but no multiplication, and Godel's theorem doesn't apply to it (it is consistent, complete and decidable). So even if Plato did say decision-making could be reduced to math (what statement of his are you thinking of?), without saying exactly what the mathematical rules are for this supposed decision process, we can't say for sure Godel's th. would apply.